# How function(x) works in R?

Tags: r, function, if-statement

```
data =data.frame(sapply(data,function(x) ifelse((x==999),NA,x)))
```

Could you explain how function(x)....,x works? I know what input and output of this function are, it just replaces 999 values with NAs in dataframe, but I want to know how this function(x) works in General.

Comment: It's an [anonymous function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/function.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is your function with the name `my_func`: It takes a value x checks if it is 999, if not it gives back the value of x, if yes it gives back 999:**

```
my_func <- function(x) {
  ifelse(x==999, NA, x)
}
```

**You now can use this function as follows:**

1. named function standalone:

```
my_func(mtcars$mpg)
```

2. As named function with `lapply` or `sapply` ...

Basically  `sapply` function in R does the same job as `lapply()` function but returns a vector:

- **lapply(X, FUN)**
  Arguments:
  -**X**: A vector or an object
  -**FUN**: Function applied to each element of x

```
lapply(mtcars$mpg, my_func)
```

- **sapply(X, FUN)**
  Arguments:
  -X: A vector or an object
  -FUN: Function applied to each element of x

```
sapply(mtcars$mpg, my_func)
```

**Now your question:**

You can use a function in this case `my_func` directly without defining or naming first as an **anonymous function** (means the function has not a name) like:

```
lapply(mtcars$mpg, function(x) ifelse(x==999, NA, x))
```

Note: essentially after `function(x)` it is the body part of your named function `my_func`.